# CGPoint relative to view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, cgpoint

Consider a screen point (CGPoint) and a view (UIView), which is somewhere inside the view hierarchy (it can be a subview of other views).

How can you convert the point to a point relative to the view's coordinates?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First, convert the point from screen coordinates to the coordinates of your main window:

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGPoint pointInWindowCoords = [mainWindow convertPoint:pointInScreenCoords fromWindow:nil];
```

Second, convert the point from window coords to view coords:

```
CGPoint pointInViewCoords = [myView convertPoint:pointInWindowCoords fromView:mainWindow];
```

Comment: Wish I'd known that a couple of weeks ago :)

Comment: +1 -- this totally saved my bacon, after I'd been messing with my own, what turned out to be, reimplementation of exactly that.  Nice! :)